# Change inflection without affecting existing routes -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails3 app. I found an issue where rails has created an incorrect singularization of one of my models.

```
rails generate model tradie
```

produces trady (singular), and (tradies) plural.

I've fixed this by adding an inflection.

config/initializers/inflection.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'tradie', 'tradies'
end
```

Now my routes have changed from

new_trady_path to new_tradie_path

breaking my existing views.

Can I override the routes to keep trady_path so I don't need to go through and update all my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to your app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def new_trady_path
  new_tradie_path
end
```

That will add this method to all your views, and you can use the new method to get the path.

Alternatively, I would just do

```
find app/views/ -print | xargs sed -i 's/new_trady_path/new_tradie_path/g'
```

or similar.